# Parsing a math formula using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I am developing a Calculator in JavaScript.  Using the Regular Expressions and the formula below:

```
8.77 + $59.09 + 8   7.6 - ((1)) + 7e-2 + 4.9e11 + cos((pi/3) + 1) + cos(((6+3)) + 1) +1.12e+12 * x_variable + e - sin(((pi/4))) / tan(4)
```

how can I return the following array?  If not possible with the use of RegEx, then with any other good strategies to achieve this?

```
['8.77', '$', '59.09', '87.6', '1', '7e-2', '4.9e11', 'cos', 'pi/3', '1', 'cos', '6+3', '1', '1.12e+12', 'x_variable', 'e', 'sin', 'pi/4', 'tan', '4']
```

I will also be happy with this result as well:

```
['8.77', '$', '59.09', '87.6', '1', '7e-2', '4.9e11', 'cos', 'pi', '3', '1', 'cos', '6', '3', '1', '1.12e+12', 'x_variable', 'e', 'sin', 'pi', '4', 'tan', '4']
```

Please note that the value of the standalone "e" is 2.7182818285, and "1.12e+12" is just an exponential number which contains "e" character, and "e" is at the end of "x_variable" string as well. Also, there are spaces in "8   7.6".

Comment: Don't you also need the operators so you can know what to do with the numbers?

Comment: Regex probably isn't the best way to do this.  A parser might be more in line with what you'd want to create.

Comment: Regex isn't the right tool for this. You'll have to use a parser, tokenize, generate an AST, evaluate according to mathematical rules like precedence etc. Same reason [why you can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/575527). There are a lot of examples on this topic online. It even shows up when talking about data structures, real-world applications of binary trees.

Comment: At this time, I really don't need the operators back.  I wrote a parser in my Calculator app, but its not a good one; this is why I am reaching out for help.  Does anyone know of any good open-source parser on the GitHub to help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As remarked in comment above, you really shouldn't do this.

But just for the fun of it...

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply(
  [],
  '8.77 + $59.09 + 8   7.6 - ((1)) + 7e-2 + 4.9e11 + cos((pi/3) + 1) + cos(((6+3)) + 1) +1.12e+12 * x_variable + e - sin(((pi/4))) / tan(4)'
    .replace(/[\s()]/g, '')
    .replace(/([-+*\/])/g, ' $1 ')
    .replace(/(\d+e) (([-|+]) )?(\d+)/g, '$1$3$4')
    .split(/(sin|cos|tan|\$)/g)
    .map(function(e) {
      return e.split(/ /g);
    })
)
.filter(function(e) {
  return e.match(/./g) && !e.match(/^[-+*/]$/g);
})
```

yields you the second result.

Handling solve, as per comments below:

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply(
  [],
  '8.77 + $59.09 + 8 7.6 - ((1)) + 7e-2 + 4.9e11 + cos((pi/3) + 1) + cos(((6+3)) + 1) +1.12e+12 * x_variable + e - sin(((pi/4))) / tan(4) + ncr(2;y_variable) + solve("2(a-2)+3a+3=13"; "a"; 1; 5)'
    .replace(/[\s]/g, '')
    .replace(/([-+*\/;])/g, ' $1 ')
    .replace(/(\d+e) (([-|+]) )?(\d+)/g, '$1$3$4')
    .replace(/solve\("([^"]*)"\s*;\s*"(.)"/g, function(m) { return m.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/solve\("(.*)"\s*;\s*"(.)"/g, 'solve $1 $2'); })
    .replace(/[()]/g, '')
    .split(/(sin|cos|tan|\$|ncr)/g)
    .map(function(e) {
      return e.split(/ /g);
    })
)
.filter(function(e) {
  return e.match(/./g) && !e.match(/^[-+*/;]$/g);
})
```

which yields

```
["8.77", "$", "59.09", "87.6", "1", "7e-2", "4.9e11", "cos", "pi", "3", "1", "cos", "6", "3", "1", "1.12e+12", "x_variable", "e", "sin", "pi", "4", "tan", "4", "ncr", "2", "y_variable", "solve", "2a-2+3a+3=13", "a", "1", "5"]
```

Comment: Yes, there's simpler ways. I'm shooting for regexes everywhere, even where a simpler solution exists.

Comment: The code snippet you added worked like a charm!  thank you

Comment: Is there a way to extend upon your code snippet to handle the below formula?

8.77 + $59.09 + 8 7.6 - ((1)) + 7e-2 + 4.9e11 + cos((pi/3) + 1) + cos(((6+3)) + 1) +1.12e+12 * x_variable + e - sin(((pi/4))) / tan(4) + ncr(2;3) + solve("2(a-2)+3a+3=13"; "a"; 1; 5)

Comment: What's the expected output?  Once again, I don't recommend using the regex approach and what I've written already is untested and probably full of bugs and corner cases.

Comment: New Formula: 8.77 + $59.09 + 8 7.6 - ((1)) + 7e-2 + 4.9e11 + cos((pi/3) + 1) + cos(((6+3)) + 1) +1.12e+12 * x_variable + e - sin(((pi/4))) / tan(4) + ncr(2;y_variable) + solve("2(a-2)+3a+3=13"; "a"; 1; 5)

Result = ['8.77', '$', '59.09', '87.6', '1', '7e-2', '4.9e11', 'cos', 'pi', '3', '1', 'cos', '6', '3', '1', '1.12e+12', 'x_variable', 'e', 'sin', 'pi', '4', 'tan', '4', 'ncr', '2', 'y_variable', 'solve("2(a-2)+3a+3=13"; "a"; 1; 5)']

Comment: Actually what you wrote worked out great for me.  I've tested it against all possible formula test I had.  The only issue that i have right now is the Solve() function in formula strings.  It would be great just get the entire Solve() functions back in seperate array cells.

Comment: The `solve()` case is a bit tricky strictly using regexes since JS regexes don't support recursion (for matching parens).  That task, however, could be done pretty easily (as could most of this problem) without regexes.

Comment: I could pretty reasonably get you `[solve, "2(a-2)+3a+3=13", a, 1, 5]` using regexes. The problem with parens is that your inner expressions can have them and there's no regex-y way to match them

Comment: Is there a way to use a separate RegEx to only extract way all the Solve() functions (Ques1) prior to executing the code snippet you provided above? If yes, also is there a way to use another RegEx to just return a list of only all Solve() funcs prior to striping them away in my Ques1 question? For example: [ 'solve("2(a-2)+3a+3=13"; "a"; 1; 5)',  'solve("x^2-6x+5=0"; "x")' ].

Comment: Once again, it's tough to do with regexes since there's no support for recursion for matching the parens.  It's easily possible to extract the `Solve()` functions, just not with [js] regexes.

Comment: I wish JS was more powerful to do this.  With your help, I am now light years ahead of what I had originally written.  In one of your earlier comments, you mentioned that you could extend the original code snippet to also output the result of ['solve', '2(a-2)+3a+3=13', 'a', '1', '5'].  I tried to modify your code to do this, but I had no luck. When you have a free moment, would you provide me with this code extension to get this result?  Thanks

Comment: Running to another issue with a simpler math expression; using this expression: -1+(-2.3+5.01) + (-0.32*444). how to return ['-1', '+', '(', '-2.3', '+', '5.01', ')', '+', '(', '-0.32', '*', '444, ')'] back? I used JS code formula.match(/[^\d]+|[\d.]+/g) and its failing for me.